# Prevent jQuery Ajax call if form is invalid using jQuery validate

Tags: forms, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery validate to validate a form and handle the form submission but can't seem to get the syntax correct and cannot find an example like mine in the API. My code is below:

```
$("#beta_form").validate({
    rules: {   
        p_emailaddress: {
            required: true,
            email :true
        } 
    }
    submitHandler : function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :'websiteUrlWithService',
            data: $('#beta_form').serialize(),
            complete: function() { 
                $('#dialog').jqmHide();
                $('#formSubmissionThanks').jqmShow();               
            }               
        });
    }
});
```

The form HTML is as follows:

```
    <form class="login_form" id="beta_form" name="beta_form">

            <label for="p_name" class="login_label">Name:</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="p_enquiry" name="p_enquiry" value="Beta Enquiry" />
            <input type="text" id="p_name" name="p_name" class="login_input" value="" />
             <br />
            <br/>
            <label for="emailaddress" class="login_label">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="p_emailaddress" name="p_emailaddress" class="login_input" value="" />
            <br />
            <br/>
            <label for="role" class="login_label">Current Role:</label>
            <select size="1" id="p_role" name="p_role">  
                  <option value="1">None Selected</option>
                  <option value="2">Recruiter</option>
                  <option value="3">HR Role</option>
                  <option value="4">Self Employed</option>

                </select>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label for="terms" class="login_label">Include me in the Beta testing selection?</label>

            <input type="checkbox" id="p_terms" name="p_terms" class="boxes login_label"/>
            <br />
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="submitbuttonbeta" class="login_submitbutton" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

When I run this with Firebug on it suggests that I'm missing a `}` after the `submitHandler` property list but as far as I can see the syntax is correct. This error is preventing my form from firing altogether.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing comma

```
$("#beta_form").validate({
       rules: {   
         p_emailaddress: {
            required: true,
            email :true
         } 
        },
       submitHandler : function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url :'websiteUrlWithService',
            data: $('#beta_form').serialize(),
            complete: function() { 
                $('#dialog').jqmHide();
                    $('#formSubmissionThanks').jqmShow();               
                }               
        });

       }
    });
```

Comment: I've now added the form HTML

Comment: I've added the jQuery library and the validate plugin. That is all. This works with just the rules on its own (remove the submithandler) however the submitHandler should prevent form submission unless the form is valid which it does not do.

Comment: Nevermind, I've solved it now. I was including the javascript in my index page which is rendered differently from the other pages (they are constructed by a pl/sql procedure). I just needed to add the javascript library reference to this procedure. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a ',' after the rules object is defined, actually...

```
$("#beta_form").validate({
   rules: {   
     p_emailaddress: {
        required: true,
        email :true
     } 
    },

   submitHandler : function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url :'websiteUrlWithService',
        data: $('#beta_form').serialize(),
        complete: function() { 
            $('#dialog').jqmHide();
                $('#formSubmissionThanks').jqmShow();               
            }               
    });

   }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding that in before posting on here but it breaks the validation so that it doesn't fire for the invalid p_emailaddress field

Comment: Is there error from the web service request?  (e.g. does submitHandler now get called?)

Comment: The validation should occur on the fly so that when the user is typing in p_emailaddress it will tell them that their form is invalid until they enter a proper email address.